# Read a txt file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader

I've got a .aspx page with some C# code in the code behind file.

I want to execute a command in the command prompt and save the output to a .txt file.  This works and a new .txt file is created.

Then I want to read the first line from the .txt file and store the string in a variable.

My current code is below, however, it throws the "The file could not be read." error message in my code.  Why is this and how can I resolve this?

**UPDATE**:
So I've modified my code from my original post and added a check to see if the 'archivo_resultado' exists before reading from it.  However, debugview outputs

```
"archivo_resultado doesn't exist."
```

so of course attempting to read it would throw an error.

What's the most efficient way to execute the following command in command prompt:

```
'ejecutable_CheckMac + " " + archivo_temporal'
```

and store the output string in a variable and to a file (archivo_resultado) ?

**code**:

```
        string ejecutable_CheckMac = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\cgi-bin\\tbk_check_mac.exe";
        var archivo_temporal = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cgi-bin\log\DatosParaCheckMac_100942.txt";
        var archivo_resultado = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\cgi-bin\log\ResultadoCheckMac_100942.txt";

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "Declare cmd variable.");
        string cmd = ejecutable_CheckMac + " " + archivo_temporal + " > " + archivo_resultado;
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "cmd: " + cmd);

        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "Start cmd execution.");
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + cmd);
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

        if (File.Exists(archivo_resultado))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "archivo_resultado exists.");             
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "archivo_resultado doesn't exist.");
        }

        string returnedLine = "";
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "Start - StreamReader to read archivo_resultado: " + archivo_resultado);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(archivo_resultado))
            {
                returnedLine = sr.ReadLine() ?? "";
                Console.WriteLine(returnedLine);
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "archivo_resultado: " + returnedLine);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "Finished - StreamReader to read archivo_resultado: " + archivo_resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex2)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, null, "The file could not be read.");
            Console.WriteLine(Ex2.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: @MrTree "The file could not be read."

Comment: You can easily read the first line using LINQ.

Comment: The most important information is missing. What are the values of the two variables _archivo_resultado_ and _archivo_temporal_?

Comment: Isn't that just what you're Logging?

Comment: Does the file archive_resultado exist?  Your streamreader can't open a file that doesn't exist.  So when the application first starts the file doesn't exist and the streamreader will throw an exception.

Comment: I would change that path to your own site APP_DATA folder. It is really possible that you don't have permissions to write/read there.

Comment: @Steve, I have set the correct permission to be able to read/write to that folder.

Comment: However, just for testing purpose, I would change that path to point to a folder where IIS default permission allows read/write to the IIS user that runs your code. I am not very fond to change the default permissions of IIS. Many subtle errors can arise from this.

Comment: when you hit the exception and you output the file could not be read, what is the output of Ex2.Message and the stacktrace too to see what this is saying

Comment: Noticed also that you have another variable here at work _ejecutable_CheckMac_ Is this the name of an executable that keeps one or both of the files open and doesn't allow other processes to access the output file?

Comment: I've modified the original post. Though executing the command should create the 'archivo_resultado' file, it appears as though it doesn't exist when I check for it - File.Exists(archivo_resultado))

Comment: This is another hint that the user impersonated by the IIS process has not the permission to read that file (of course, if you don't have simple error in your paths)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string checkMacOutcome = "";
        var psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(ejecutable_CheckMac, archivo_temporal);
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using (var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = proc.StandardOutput)
            {
                checkMacOutcome = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(archivo_resultado);
        writetext.WriteLine(checkMacOutcome);
        writetext.Close();
```